# jQuery autocomplete from two sources

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a question about possibility to put two sources in one autocomplete field. What I have at this moment is:

One field autocompletes from geocoder:

```
$('#field').autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response){
                    geocoder.geocode({'address': request.term}, function(results){
                        response($.map(results, function(item){
                            return {
                                label:item.formatted_address,
                                value: item.formatted_address,
                                latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
                                longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
                            }
                        }));
                    });
                },
                select: function(event, ui){
                    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
                    map.setCenter(location);
                }
    });
```

and the other field completes from the database:

```
$('#companies').autocomplete({
        source: 'pages/autocomplete.php',
        minLength: 3,
        select: function(event, ui){
            var broj = ui.item.id;
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude));
            $.post('pages/results.php', {broj: broj}, function(data){
               $('#content').html(data); 
            });
        }
    });
```

this works just fine separately, but what I would like is to put everything on one field so that I could search everything in there.

Comment: Can you show some of work where you've attempted to combine the two sources of data?

Comment: Seems like the first one returns a json reply, the second one looks like it might just dump out a bunch of html? Is that correct? To combine the two you will probably want to alter your `pages/autocomplete.php` file so that it returns data in json and can be easily merged.